# A couple of applications configured under one site don't work consistently when debugging in .Net 6.0 app with VS 2022 & IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, iis-express

Context: Windows 2016, VS 2022 - 17.5.1 (latest version as of right now, 2023-Mar-13), .Net 6.0 F# web app using the Giraffe framework, IIS Express 10 (product version 10.0.25095.1000).

Note: I run VS 2022 in Admin mode.

When I run the app in development mode in VS 2022 with IIS Express, I want to redirect the `/Scripts` path to a different folder that contains a zillion JavaScript, css, images etc. files: `d:\webapps\webroot\Scripts`.

Here is what I have in the `applicationhost.config` file:

```
        <applicationPools>
            <add name="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr4ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2IntegratedAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="Clr2ClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v2.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" CLRConfigFile="%IIS_USER_HOME%\config\aspnet.config" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="UnmanagedClassicAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="" managedPipelineMode="Classic" autoStart="true" />
            <add name="MyApp AppPool" managedRuntimeVersion=""/>
            <add name="MyApp AppPool 2" autoStart="true" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
                <processModel />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>
...
   <sites>
         <site name="MyApp" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="MyApp AppPool">
                   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\webapps\webroot" />
                </application>
                <application path="/MyApp" applicationPool="MyApp AppPool 2">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\webapps\MyApp\src\MyApp" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51582:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44339:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
   </sites>
```

The problem that I have is that any request under /Scripts returns a 404.

web.config (development):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="logs/stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44339" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The configuration you see above used to work in the previous version of VS 2022 that I had. Not anymore. Maybe it was the upgrade to 17.5.1 that broke it - I upgraded VS 2022 on Thursday. What's worse is that, today, it worked for while, then it stopped working which is not a good sign. I restarted VS 2022 of course, but I didn't reboot windows. I think I should not have have to do it. I have lots of apps that I use that are open.

Here are some things I noticed:

- If I run IIS Express from the command line with following command: `"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"D:\webapps\MyApp\src\.vs\MyApp\config\applicationhost.config" /site:"MyApp"` everything works fine (as long as I previously set `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` and  `set LAUNCHER_PATH=D:\webapps\MyApp\src\MyApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\MyApp.exe`.
- The app url is `htts://localhost:44339/MyApp/`.
- VS 2022 launches IIS Express with the following command: `"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"  /config:"D:\webapps\MyApp\src\.vs\MyApp\config\applicationhost.config" /site:"MyApp" /apppool:"MyApp AppPool 2"`. Note the `/apppool` argument. It is not documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line. I have a hunch that this parameter is what's causing the issue. Perhaps it tells IIS Express to start the `MyApp AppPool 2`, and it's ignoring the other pool, `MyApp AppPool`. But I might be wrong here because I also tried adding the `autoStart=true` attribute for the `MyApp AppPool` pool and it didn't work. I set `applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool"` for `application path="/"` but that didn't work either.
- The Debug Properties dialog (available under the IIS Express dropdown) -> IIS Express profile has a Command Line arguments box where theoretically you specify different parameters, however, anything I set here didn't override the parameters set automatically by VS 2022.

So, at this point I am stumped. Do you have any suggestion or ideas of how to get this configuration working when I debug the app inside VS 2022?

TIA

**Update**: I rebooted windows - the problem still persists after the restart.

**Update 2**: I rolled back VS 2022 from 17.5.1 to 17.4.4. IIS Express is the same version. I created a new profile in `launchSettings.json`, and when I run the project using this profile the web app works as expected, in other words the requests under the scripts folder `http://localhost:44339/scripts/...` don't fail anymore with 404:

```
    "Profile 1": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "commandLineArgs": "/config:\"D:\\webapps\\MyApp\\src\\.vs\\MyApp\\config\\applicationhost.config\" /site:\"MyApp\"",
      "workingDirectory": "D:\\webapps\\MyApp\\src\\MyApp",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "use64Bit": true
    }
```

Note that, even though commandLineArgs is set, that value doesn't seem to go anywhere. I inspected the iisexpress.exe process properties with process explorer and the command line still contains the `/apppool` parameter. I also tried to set environment variables in the `launchSettings.json` using the UI but nothing had any impact on the iisexpress.exe command line parameters invoked by VS 2022.

**Update 3**: If you use Rider.Net, Rider supports a setting in Edit configurations for IIS Express called `Additional IIS Express arguments`. If the arguments above are set in this field then Rider.Net works properly as well. Please note that Rider.Net has another issue and that is it keeps generating the applicationhost.config file (placed under the `.idea` folder) and overwriting any changes but specifying a different applicationhost.config file circumvents this issue.

Comment: Not to be surprised. 1) Learn how ASP.NET Core module was configured in `web.config`. That tells you all requests (including static files) go to ASP.NET Core and handled by your web app. 2) Your web app, however, use `d:\webapps\webroot\wwwroot` as root directory for static files, if you read carefully the ASP.NET Core documentation. That's why `d:\webapps\webroot\Scripts` simply won't work.

Comment: Can you please point me to the specific ASP.NET Core documentation that says I cannot use this configuration? This is an issue with IIS express, not with asp.net core. In production, the web files (css, images etc.) are served from a different folder.

Comment: @LexLi: I added the content of the web.config file. Any issues with it?

Comment: I won't comment more as my initial comment contains all details I think needed in this case, applicable to both IIS and IIS Express. You will find it super easy to follow the design https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-static-files, but if you want to hack around you also know where to get started.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks - Yes, you are right in pointing out that the static folders outside the webroot can be served using the app. In my case, the static files I point to are already deployed in production (we use IIS), and I want these files to be served by the web server (IIS), not by the application.

Answer (score 1):

In my Update 2 I wrote I got it working (VS 2022, 17.4.4). That joy was of a short duration. I installed VS 2022 17.5.2 (available today, 2022-Mar-14), and it stopped working. VS 2022 + IIS Express is a very finicky combination and I gave up after spending so much time testing and trying different combinations. I decided to follow the suggestion from the comments and I handled the requests from the app in the development mode. Here are the relevant changes:

applicationhost.config:

```xml
   <sites>
         <site name="MyApp" id="2">
               <!-- <application path="/" applicationPool="MyApp AppPool">
                   <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\webapps\webroot" />
                </application> -->
                <application path="/" applicationPool="MyApp AppPool 2">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\webapps\MyApp\src\MyApp" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51582:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44339:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
   </sites>
```

F# code:

```ml
let configureApp (app : IApplicationBuilder) =
    let env = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()
    //(match env.IsDevelopment() with
    //| true  -> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
    //| false -> app.UseGiraffeErrorHandler errorHandler)
    let appBuilder = 
      app
        .UseGiraffeErrorHandler(errorHandler)
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseHttpsRedirection()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseCors(configureCors)
        .UseStaticFiles()
    
    (
      if env.IsDevelopment() then
        let serviceProvider = app.ApplicationServices
        let config: IConfiguration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>()
        let staticFileOptions = StaticFileOptions(
            RequestPath = (PathString) "/scripts",
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(config.GetValue("ScriptsRoot"))
        )
        appBuilder.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions)
      else
        appBuilder

    ).UseGiraffe(webApp)
```

where I have a setting in appsettings.json, "ScriptsRoot" that points to the folder that is the root for all the scripts files.

Side note, I found this article interesting: https://wildermuth.com/2022/04/25/multiple-directories-for-static-files-in-aspnetcore/ when it comes to serving files from multiple directories.